# Preloading then adding additional images after page load to an image gallery on button click

Tags: javascript, image-gallery

I am building an image gallery that is populated from a JSON file. Everything works as intended currently, but as of right now there is no pre-loading of content after the initial page load. What I would like to happen is after the "view more" button is clicked I will have some "loading" text show, the batch of images will preload, the "loading" text will disappear, then the images will be added to the page once all items have loaded.

Here is the section of the code that involves the JSON fetch request and the building of elements on the page:

```
var HTML = '';
var itemsStart = 6; // Starting number of items on page.
var itemsAdd = 9; // Number of items to add to page at a time via button click.
var pItems = document.getElementById('pItems');
var pWrapper = document.getElementById('pItemWrapper');

function addProjects() {
    pItems.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', HTML);
    console.log('BUILD PROJECTS');
}

//Load json
fetch('data/projects.json').then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
}).then(function (data){

    //Loop through first set of items to load on page.
    for (var i = 0; i < itemsStart; i++) {
        HTML += '<img src="' + data.projects[i].Image + '" alt=""></img>';
         
        if (i == (itemsStart - 1)) {
            addProjects();
        }
    }

    //Load additional items when clicking 'view more'.
    document.getElementById('view-more').addEventListener('click', function() {
        HTML = '';
        for (var i = itemsStart; i < itemsStart + itemsAdd; i++) {
            if ((i < data.projects.length)) {
                HTML += '<img src="' + data.projects[i].Image + '" alt=""></img>';
            }
            
            if (i == ((itemsStart + itemsAdd) - 1) )   {
                addProjects();
            }
        }
        itemsStart = itemsStart + itemsAdd;
    });

}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Something went wrong');
});
```

I'm not using jQuery so I'd like to stick to vanilla js. I don't know what I need to add to my button event listener beyond what I have, I've never tried preloading images like this without using a plugin but I feel like I don't need to load an entire plugin just for this one thing and I'd like to understand how this would work.

**EDIT**

---

I feel like I'm almost there, but I still have something wrong. I made some modifications to have each item inside its own container, but instead of that happening I am creating an empty container for each pass of the loop, then the last container gets each image added to it. My code looks like this:

```
var itemsAdd = 3;

//Load additional items when clicking 'view more'.
document.getElementById('view-more').addEventListener('click', function() {

//The loop will add the next 3 items in the json file per click.
    for (var i = itemsStart; i < itemsStart + itemsAdd; i++) {

        var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
        var src = 'img/portfolio/' + data.projects[i].url;
        placeholder.innerHTML= '<div class="img-container"><a href="projects/'+ data.projects[i].ImageName +'" class="fig-container">' + data.projects[i].Title + '</a></div>';
        var galleryItem = placeholder.firstChild;

        preloadImage(src).then(function (image) {
            galleryItem.append(image);
        });
        
        pItems.append(galleryItem);  
    }
    itemsStart = itemsStart + itemsAdd;
});
```

The result I get is this:

[image]

Is this because of how the promise works for the preloadImage function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you would create an image with JavaScript through either [`document.createElement('img')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) or the [`Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) constructor. Both result an in instance of an [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

With this, you'll have an image that is not connected to the DOM, so it's not visible to you or the user. You can use this element to load the image behind the scenes by setting the image' [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/src) property.

Then by listening to the `onload` event you can determine whenever the image has finished loading. From here you could continue your flow by adding the image to the DOM and, for example, fade it in with animation.

The example below shows this process in the form of a function that returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This promise will resolve whenever the load event has been triggered.

```js
const preloadImage = src => 
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const image = new Image();
    const onLoad = () => {
      resolve(image);
    };
    image.addEventListener('load', onLoad, {once: true});
    image.src = src;
  });
```

Using it should be like this:

```
const src = 'http://example.com/my-image.jpg';
preloadImage(src).then(image => {
  // Here the image has been loaded and is available to be appended, or otherwise.
  document.body.append(image);
});
```

In your case you would loop over each image, call the function while passing the URL of the image, and append the image to the DOM when it's finished loading.

You can handle any animations, like fade-ins with CSS.

## Real world implementation

So how should you implement this in your project? You'll need to start at the point where you create your images. Currently your images are created as strings. But strings are just strings, they aren't HTML elements, yet.

I'd recommend that you'll create a placeholder for each image. This placeholder could visually indicate that an image is loading and act as a wrapper for the image. Add this placeholder immediately to the `pItems` element.

Then load the image for each `Image` in your `data.projects` array by calling the `preloadImage`. Whenever the image is loaded, append it to the placeholder we've just created. You should now have the effect that first a placeholder is added and the images are starting to appear one by one.

**The same logic should be applied for the load more loop.**

```
...
}).then(function (data){
  for (let i = 0; i < itemsStart; i++) {

    // Create a <div class="placeholder"> which should act as a placeholder / wrapper.
    const placeholder = document.createElement('div');
    placeholder.classList.add('placeholder');

    // Create the image based on the Image value.
    // Whenever the image is loaded, add it to the placeholder.
    const src = data.projects[i].Image;
    preloadImage(src).then(image => { 
      placeholder.append(image);
    });

    // Immediately add the placeholder.
    // This line doesn't wait for preloadImage to finish because preloadImage is asynchronous. Look into Promises if that is new to you.
    pItems.append(placeholder); 
  }

  ...
});
```

From here you've got control over how the placeholder should look and any animations an image inside that placeholder should have.

Comment: Hi Emiel, Thanks for your reply.  I'm trying out your method with what I have, but I'm running into an issue. With my loop for the button I am basically generating html, and then once all the html has been created I am adding it to the DOM with my addProjects(); function. Should I not be doing it this way? I don't think I want to just add the image to anything if the elements haven't been created yet.

Comment: While you *can* generate HTML as a string, you won't be able to interact with it before it has been added to the DOM. Because the HTML is no more than just strings at this point. Creating elements with `document.createElement()` will allow you to listen to events, add property values, and use methods some elements have. I would suggest that you loop over your data, append a <div> as a placeholder in your grid, and start preloading the image. Whenever the image has finished loading, append it to the earlier created <div>. I'll add more instructions in the answer.

Comment: I've added another example where I've modified your first loop and implemented this technique.

Comment: Thanks again Emiel. I tried your recommended solution and I'm getting closer! Everything looks like it's building as I hoped, except the images are all going into the last placeholder instead of going into their own respective ones. I modified my original question to show how I tried to apply what you suggested. Am I getting this result because of how the promise works? I am new to them but hoping this will help my understanding.

Comment: The promise runs as expected. You're experiencing a scoping issue with the `var` keyword. `var` is function or globally scoped. That means that every occurence of `var` in a `for` loop will be overwritten in each iteration; because in this case it is a global variable. This means that every `var placeholder` will be overwritten in each time the loop passes over it. This results in the `placeholder` variable pointing to the last created <div>. Because the images are still loading, they will be appended to the latest value of the `placeholder` variable, meaning the last div in the loop.

Comment: Since ES6, we've got access to [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) which are *block scoped* variables. These keywords allow us to create variables that are created in a scope of a block, like a `for` loop, and won't be overwritten in the next iteration. So I'd suggest that you copy this syntax in your code, because it works and solves the exact problem you're facing.

Comment: Ahhh! You're right! I was told not to mix ES5 and ES6, so I was trying to keep things in the older syntax. Looks like I can't do that, so I guess I will try to start converting all my old code to the newer syntax. Thanks for your help, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could put a `<div>` with black background over the loading image using css and when the image is ready remove it with js. You can detect when the image is loaded using the `img.onload = () => {}` function.

Or you could place there an img with the loading screen and replace it with the actual image when the image has loaded.